# How do I disable apt and snap update notifications? 22.04 LTS

Tags: updates, 22.04, notification

I have apt-daily and apt-daily-upgrade disabled, yet I still get popup windows to install system updates, even when disconnected from the internet.

I also get random notifications through GNOME about updating snap apps. *Not* the impending closure notification, but a notification that just tells me I have updates needing to be installed. Again, even when disconnected from the internet.

snap-store is not running, and I can't find a relevant entry in the GNOME notification settings.